# Необходимо в настройках комплекта задать компилятор для сборки

Tags: qt

Я новичок в QT. Только установил и хотел запустить простейшую программу, как стало при нажатии на "Запустить" выдавать "Необходимо в настройках комплекта задать компилятор для сборки". Но у меня компилятор вроде и так выбран.

Не пойму, что не так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У Вас значок в Комплектах, указывающий на некое предупреждение. Вот что там обозначено?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте, что Kit (комплект) "Desktop Qt 5.4.2 MSVC2013 64bit" выбран для проекта, а не какой-то другой (красный прямоугольник):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если не тот, выберите правильный комплект (зелёный прямоугольник). Ну и в настройках комплекта подведите указатель, что бы узнать причину по которой горит желтый знак (в вашем случае похоже на отсутствие отладчика).